# How to get algebraic PSG solutions once we got the constraints?

Tags: condensed-matter, research-level, topological-order, topological-phase, spin-models

The question is more technical than conceptual. I've been trying to understand the classification of spin liquids as done by Prof.Wen. I have got the constraints on IGG(Invariant gauge group) elements for Z2 spin liquid solutions as given in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0107071). I have been stuck on how to get the list of all gauge equivalent solutions as given in Appendix A(2) of Prof. Wen's [work](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0107071).
Can anyone please help out to get the solutions?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Maybe link a reference showing such a list?